# Rookie mistake:Trying to pass outgoing number to activity

Tags: java, android

I am retrieving the outgoing number from the broadcast receiver and trying to send it to the activity thru a method getNumber() however the value is coming out null. Im my code below In the activity class the String phonenumber is null

BroadcastReciever  Class:

```
public class OutgoingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

String phonenumber = null;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


     phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
  if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
    {


         Log.i("System out", "IN OUTGOING CALL......... :IF");
         MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener(
                     context);
             TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                     .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
             telephony.listen(phoneListener,
                     PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
     }    else {         
             Log.i("System out", "IN INCOMING CALL.........:else:receiver");           




}
public String getNumber()
{
    return phonenumber;
}
```

Activity Class:

```
public class OutgoingCallScreenDisplay extends Activity
```

{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.outgoing_main);
    OutgoingBroadcastReceiver outreciever = new  OutgoingBroadcastReceiver();

    String phonenumber= outreciever.getNumber();//this is coming out NULL needs to be the outgoing number






}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phone no. is null because u r making a new instance of broadcastreceiver whose values are not initilized. You can receive a phone no. in "onReceive" ONLY ,from there u should start a new activity if u want to pass it further

See:

Firstly you shud either use a broadcast receiver or a phone state listener. In ur case if u r using a broadcast receiver then u simple need intent extra:EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER
and permission : process outgoin call   .That's it.....

Comment: Thanks that makes total sense! but I am passing it to a PhoneStateListner before I send to activity so I cannot pass directly to activity...Any idea?

Comment: Solved it with an my phonestatelistner as an inner class to my BroadcastReciever

Answer (score 0):

Two things immediately come to mind:

- The `onReceive` method needs to be called before you can get the phone number.
- You are assigning the phone number to a local variable and not the instance member.

Comment: After debugging I am getting the value correctly in the BroadcastReciever. I  think its because of the second thing you said but I have removed the String from the local variable but still same result....Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

use [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) if you want to pass data to an activity